# Akka's ActorSystem Shutdown?

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

please
how to shutdown actorSystem after all childs' actors finished

```
system().shutdown //cut actors work
```

i try to use

```
system().shutdown
```

but this cut other actors work

and schedule may finish before child actors finished

Comment: Your question is not clear - can you explain your question in greater detail, provide extra code etc? Please see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for how to write good questions.

Comment: Create a supervisor and watch for all children to terminate. After the last child is gone do `shutdown`.

Answer (score 5):

The Derek Wyatt's article Shutdown Patterns in Akka 2 (http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2) gives the comprehensive answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

For testing this works just fine. You will be able to use sbt ~run

```
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(20 seconds) {
    println("shutdown")
    system.shutdown
}
```

Comment: schedule may finish before child actors finished